# How to remove previous account in heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

i have to switch heroku account from one to another .i tried using heroku login.but when i try to deploy my app using command

```
git push heroku master
```

but i am getting error

```
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.

 !  Your account ritesh@iritesh.com does not have access to young-plains-9347.
 !  
 !  SSH Key Fingerprint: 3f:bf:62:23:04:b3:7a:ff:a8:15:59:43:37:c0:4d:6e

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

where ritesh@iritesh.com is my previous account .how to get rid of this error ??please guideline .

Comment: I am running into the same issue . Could you please  share what worked for you ?

Comment: use heroku logout remove the ssh keys from locals desktop and add new keys generated for your new account and again login with heroku login command and its all fixed :D

Comment: I have account but its key is no longer in my pc.. still getting same error as yours how can i get out of this problemmmm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Heroku accounts](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts) to switch between multiple Heroku accounts. Also see the [Dev Center article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
#list of accounts
heroku accounts

#Remove a account
heroku accounts:remove personal

#Set a new account # in project root
heroku accounts:set personal

#Set machine wide default account
heroku accounts:default personal
```

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out after 4 hours struggling.

To simply remove previous account,

1. just uninstall Herouku toolbelt completely.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command#uninstalling-the-heroku-cli

2. restart computer
3. reinstall it
4. login heroku in terminal
5. create ssh following Heroku guide.

Done! That simply removes previous account.

Answer (score 1):

To remove previous account you should logout from command line:

```sh
heroku logout
```

And login again to add new account:

```sh
heroku login
```

You can manage multi accounts for heroku by installing [heroku accounts package](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to heroku toolbelt per-se. What happens in your case probably is that the git (through ssh-agent) is unaware of the ssh key of the account you are trying to use, assuming that you have one (if you don't have one, you need to generate one and add it through `heroku keys:add`).

All you need to do is to add the ssh key to the user agent by running `ssh-add ~/.ssh/your-other-ssh-key`. If ssh-agent is not running already, you can start it using `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`.